# C: binary tree searching method

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to make a search method using a binary tree(no, it's not a binary search tree, just a binary tree) using a recursive function. If the data is on the binary tree, i want it to return the node and if it is not, i want it to return a `NULL` value. I have made the search function and it's doing its job perfectly. But the problem is, it seems that the function won't return the node.

Here's the `struct` for the binary tree:

```
struct data
{
    int number;
    struct data *left, *right;
}*root = NULL;
```

and this is the search function i'm talking about:

```
data* search(struct data *node, int key)
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d %d -", node->number, key);

        if(node->number== key)
            return node;

        search(node->left, key);
        search(node->right, key);
    }
}
```

When i'm calling the search function like this: `search(root, 6);` , it says that it's returning a `NULL` value although i have pushed a `6` number into the binary tree(and the search function stops right at the `return node;` line too, so i'm assuming that the function is returning a `NULL`.)

I have seen a tutorial for binary tree in [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html)  , used and changed some code from it, but it's still the same. i'm desperately looking for help right here :(

Comment: C or C++? Fundamentally different beasts.

Comment: When some invocation returns a non-null pointer, what happens to that value?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: actually it's C, but i'm using a C++ compiler, so, i think it won't be a problem . .

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: i'm not sure if i'm answering this right, but when it's not returning a non-null value, i want to push another data to the tree.

Comment: @aquatorrent It might not be a problem but that’s not why I asked. Rather, a good C++ solution would look completely different, and hence good advice should take this into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Your function will always return `NULL`, except when the top node contains the key.</del> Your function does not do anything with the results from its recursive invocations; in fact, control flow may "fall off the end" of it without hitting a `return` statement.

You should check the return values from the recursive invocations and pass those up when appropriate:

```
if (node == NULL)
    return NULL;
else if (node->number == key)
    return node;
else {
    data *left = search(node->left, key);
    return left? left: search(node->right, key);
}
```

Note the "ternary operator" (if-then-else expression) `?:`.

Comment: Sorry, but -1. When control flows off the end of the function after the recursive calls, you can't depend on it returning NULL (or anything else in particular).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: it won't. The return values of the recursive calls are used in a `return` statement.

Comment: It's not running off the end--it's always returning one of three cases: NULL if node == NULL, node if node->number == key, and (data* || data*) in the third case.  

If the first search returns non-NULL, its value is used; if the second search returns non-NULL, its value is used; otherwise, it returns (data*)(0||0), which happens to be NULL.

Comment: @larsmans: I'm not talking about your function (which is fine) but your statement that "Your function will always return NULL..." In his function, after the recursive calls, control flows off the end without returning any value. The precise result of that is (if memory serves) different between C and C++, but you certainly can't depend on it being NULL.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: you're right, hadn't spotted that. Fixed it now.

Comment: Is this `||` construction C-specific? In C++ I would expect compilation error because you can't convert `bool` to `data*` Edit: OK, I see the C++ tag disappeared ;)

Comment: @Fiktik: nope, I was actually wrong about `||`'s semantics. I've been doing too much Python lately. Replaced it with an `?:`.

Answer (score 1):

it will not return the searched node unless you use the return value of you `search`

change it to something like this.

```
data* search(struct data *node, int key)
{
  if(node == NULL)
    return NULL;
  else
  {
    printf("\n%d %d -", node->number, key);

    if(node->number== key)
        return node;
    struct data *tmp;
    tmp = search(node->left, key);
    /* node found ? */
    if (tmp)
        return tmp;
    tmp = search(node->right, key);
    /* node found ? */
    if (tmp)
        return tmp;
  }
  /* search didn't find anything */
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're never actually returning the result from the recursive calls to search.

You need to check the return value from those calls, and if they found the node, return it

```
data* search(struct data *node, int key)
{
    data* found = NULL;

    if(node == NULL)
        return NULL;

    printf("\n%d %d -", node->number, key);

    if(node->number== key)
        return node;

    found = search(node->left, key);
    if (found)
        return found;

    found = search(node->right, key);
    if (found)
       return found;

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier and more efficient way to make a binary tree, and that's simply with a vector/array.

i is the int to access your vector. To go right, i=i*2. to go left, i=i*2+1. They will never share a same spot and assuming equal distribution each spot will be taken.